# Do 7 to 12 year olds need 10 to 11 hours of sleep per day?

Tags: sleep, children

> [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/guide/sleep-children?page=): 7-12 Years Old: 10 - 11 hours per day
>
> At these ages, with social, school, and family activities, bedtimes gradually become later and later, with most 12-years-olds going to bed at about 9 p.m. There is still a wide range of bedtimes, from 7:30 to 10 p.m., as well as total sleep times, from 9 to 12 hours, although the average is only about 9 hours.

Is there scientific research that backs those numbers for the need of sleep of children?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there scientific research that backs those numbers for the need of sleep of children?

It is not known. This is the trend:

> Total average sleep was estimated at more than 13 hours a day for infants, decreasing steadily throughout childhood and early adolescence, reaching about 9 hours a day for 14- to 18-year-olds. ... These estimates are consistent with the amount of sleep recommended for children, and no evidence was found of racial/ethnic differences [1].

But a comment [2] on this study states that:

> ... we are still far from understanding what a "normal", "ideal" or "adequate" sleep duration is for an individual child to promote optimal health and functioning.

And there is a general belief that children need more sleep:

> A lack of empirical evidence for sleep recommendations was universally acknowledged. Inadequate sleep was seen as a consequence of "modern life," associated with technologies of the time. No matter how much sleep children are getting, it has always been assumed that they need more [3].

---

References:

1. Williams JA, Zimmerman FJ, Bell JF. [Norms and trends of sleep time among US children and adolescents.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23403646) JAMA Pediatr. 2013 Jan;167(1):55-60. doi: [10.1001/jamapediatrics.2013.423](http://dx.doi.org/10.1001/jamapediatrics.2013.423). PubMed PMID: 23403646.
2. Jenni OG. [How much sleep is "normal" in children and adolescents?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23403792) JAMA Pediatr. 2013 Jan;167(1):91-2. doi: [10.1001/jamapediatrics.2013.429](http://dx.doi.org/10.1001/jamapediatrics.2013.429). PubMed PMID: 23403792.
3. Matricciani LA, Olds TS, Blunden S, Rigney G, Williams MT. [Never enough sleep: a brief history of sleep recommendations for children.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22331340) Pediatrics. 2012 Mar;129(3):548-56. doi: [10.1542/peds.2011-2039](http://dx.doi.org/10.1542/peds.2011-2039). PubMed PMID: 22331340.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, there does appear to be some scientific experimental evidence to support these hours**.

> In the longitudinal study of adolescents by Carskadon, time in bed was
>   fixed at 10 hours a night, and the data showed that youngsters across
>   the span of ages 10 to 17 slept about 9 hours and 20 minutes. The
>   younger children were more likely to waken spontaneously in the lab,
>   whereas the older children took a bit longer to fall asleep and were
>   rarely spontaneously awake at the end of the 10 hours.[1]

Even though younger children and adolescents slept the same hours, the latter were less alert across the day

> Furthermore, assessment with the multiple sleep latency test (MSLT, an
>   objective measure of sleepiness) showed that the younger children were
>   more alert across the day, whereas the pubertal and postpubertal
>   adolescents showed a midday trough of alertness in spite of the same
>   amount of nocturnal sleep [2]

and the need for sleep only diminishes in late adolescence

> In summary, current data on the maturation of the biological
>   regulation of sleep during adolescence show that:
>
> - the circadian timing system undergoes a phase delay;
> - the dissipation of sleep homeostatic pressure does not change until late adolescence when it shows evidence of slowing;
> - the accumulation of sleep homeostastic pressure slows during puberty.
>
> These findings support the notion that the need for sleep is stable
>   (or increases) acrosse adolescent development and that the delay of
>   sleep timing is supported by the circadian shift as well as the
>   slowing of sleep homeostatic pressure accumulation. [3]

---

[1] Carskadon MA, Orav EJ, Dement WC. Evolution of sleep and daytime sleepiness in adolescents. In: Guilleminault C, Lugaresi E, editors. Sleep/wake disorders: Natural history, epidemiology, and long-term evolution. Raven Press; New York: 1983. pp. 201–16.

[2] Carskadon MA, Harvey K, Duke P, Anders TF, Litt IF, Dement WC. [Pubertal changes in daytime sleepiness.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7403744) Sleep. 1980;2(4):453-60. PubMed PMID: 7403744.

[3] Carskadon MA. [Sleep in adolescents: the perfect storm.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21600346) Pediatr. Clin. North Am. 2011 Jun;58(3):637-47. doi: [10.1016/j.pcl.2011.03.003](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.pcl.2011.03.003). PubMed PMID: 21600346.